# Run PHP Query with Ajax return data in modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my first fully attempting to use ajax. I have looked all over Google and cannot seem to find an answer.  I am not even sure if what I am trying to do is possible.

I am trying to populate a modal window with data from a mysql table.

Using this javascript below, I an able to print the DATA-ID in a modal window with an HREF click:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).on("click", ".open-RestrictModal", function () {
     var myId = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #Id").val( myId );
 });
 </script>
```

I would like to add to this code is the ability to run a PHP/MySQL query, get the results, and print it in the modal window.

I think I have to use AJAX, but I am not sure.  How can I add to the existing code the ability to send the javascript variable to an AJAX page and return the results in a modal window?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you are even using ajax here, assuming you are using the jQuery library you can build a call like this:

```
function some_ajax_call(your_param) {

     $.ajax({

         type: "POST",     // We want to use POST when we request our PHP file
         url : "some/url/to/your/file.php",
         data : { query : your_param },    // passing an array to the PHP file with the param,  value you passed, this could just be a single value i.e. data: your_param
         cache: false,       // disable the cache optional

         // Success callback if the PHP executed  
         success: function(data) {
              // do somethig - i.e. update your modal with the returned data object
              $('.modal-body #id').val(data);    
         }

     });

}
```

You can then write you `file.php` file to handle the query

```
<?php

// Capture the variable we passed in via AJAX
$param  = $_POST['query'];  

// Build a query
$query = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE val ='" . $param . "'";

// I assume you know how to run a query, this would be fetching an assoc array
$results = $DB->run__query($query);

// Check we have some results, then echo back to the AJAX call
if(sizeof($results) > 0) {
    echo $results;
}
```

echoing at the `$results` array at the end of our PHP script if we have any results will populate the data array in our success callback with the returned rows, you can then perform any DOM manipulation in the success callback to update your modal, hope this helps.

Comment: I can burn your DB with that code. And instead of $('.modal-body #id").val(data);``  use `$('.modal-body #id').val(data);`. Downvoted right away. And NEVER do this: `if(sizeof($results) > 0) {echo $results;} else { echo null;}`. There is no need for the `else`!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I wasn't posting a "best practices for DB security" post, I was merely pointing the OP in the right direction so he can understand the fundamentals behind how to use AJAX.  Feel free to update my answer with PDO bindings if you wish.

Comment: I'm not saying PDO bindings. Even the crappy `mysql_real_escape_string` would be better than this. You point him into a pit.

Comment: I do: You append directly user-input into 2 strings to form a query and run it right away.

Comment: Feel free to write an answer with better practices for DB calls :)

Comment: Well, that would be considered a duplicated answer, since the only bad thing here is the breach in the query.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  I will attempt to utilize both techniques.  @Alex, thank you for your prompt response.